# how to deal with when two cassandra nodes down

Tags: cassandra

**Environment**
RF=3,CL=LOCAL_QUORUM,Vnode

**Issue**

there are three replicats in cassandra cluster,if one node down,there is no problem,as we still have two relicats in cassandra.if two nodes down at the same
time which i think would always happen once there are hundreds of nodes in cassandra.there is a great possibility that there are common records of the two down nodes.so client will read fail when request the common records.

I can downgrade the consistency level in some query but not all querys.so is there any solution to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

There's no magic here - if you have RF=3, quorum or local quorum queries require two nodes up to succeed

You can:

- Drop the consistency level of the query to ONE, which allows you to continue to be available but you may have slightly less consistency / durability than you need, or
- Increase RF to 5 or add another data center, both of which will allow you to tolerate two node failures at the same time
- Use racks to divide your cluster space into smaller zones, so it's less likely that two nodes serving the same data fail at the same time

Many operators of very large clusters avoid using vnodes for a variety of reasons, but one important reason is that it makes adjacency harder to reason about - in the single-token case, it's very unlikely that two nodes failing are adjacent in a hundred node cluster.

Comment: Sorry, you're right - it won't limit node failures, but it will limit node failures caused by underlying infrastructure failure. In most real world environments, these are the PRIMARY types of outages you should see. If you're really seeing multiple hardware simultaneous hardware failures on a hundred node cluster that aren't tied to shared infrastructure, you've got some other problem to solve.

Comment: hardware failures is important thing,but what i most worry about is cassandra service.cassandra may OOM,or other reason,goes down.devlops will fear once two nodes down in different racks.I plan to use downgrade CL and switch other region datacenter.on the other hand,calculate the same data in two down nodes may need to do.

Comment: actually i do confuse about your opinion on vnodes in large clusters.vnodes can distribute data balance when bootstrapping.I can understand that this advantage will be reduced when the cluster is large.but more complex when deploy with single-token.and the large cluster become large step by step,not at the begining.cannot use sing-token when cluster is small,then switch to vnode when the cluster is large.I always think vnode is a better choice,also found it is a default configuration.

Comment: Vnodes stream faster and let you grow one node at a time. Once you bootstrap a node, you'll have a LOT of compaction to do.

Single node takes calculation, but allows you to grow by "hundreds" of nodes at a time. Because fewer streaming senders are sending data, there's far less compaction to do upon completion. 

It isn't easy to change from vnodes to single token or vice versa - you can sorta do it using extra datacenters, but it's nontrivial. 

If you expect to need to bootstrap more than one node at a time, for example if you have hundreds of nodes, you probably want single token.

Comment: you are right.a good point about token range management which I have nof found in other documents.a coin has two sides.i need to take more consideration about how to manage my token in cassandra cluster.